# Добавление товара с несколькими значениями одного атрибута в корзину

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Друзья! Задача такая. 
Имеется самописный конструктор (просто несколько полей, значения в которых влияют на цену)
Так же имеется в каталоге сам товар, то бишь "Конструктор". Данный товар вариативный. Вариации у него соответственно, поля, про которые я писал выше.

Например: `цвет, ширина, высота`

У атрибута **цвет** есть следующие значения: `Жёлтый, Красный, Синий`

У **ширины** и **высоты** просто забита размерная сетка.

Задача такая, как добавить в корзину товар, у которого будет сразу два значения из атрибута "**Цвет**"? 
Пример заказа:

```
Цвет: Синий, Красный
Ширина: 10
Высота: 15
```

Добавляю товар из формы, где указываю как раз нужные атрибуты, а так же `variation_id и product_id`

в итоге, параметры, которые уходят в корзину:

```
attribute_pa_color = ???
attribute_pa_height = 15
attribute_pa_width = 10
variation_id = 888
product_id = 1
```

Т.е. если по одному значению добавляю, то всё ок, вопросов нет. Проблема добавлении нескольких значений.

Подскажите, куда копать или вообще другой способ реализации данной задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [@Kirill Korushkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236197/kirill-korushkin) за наводку

Решил таким способом

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_store_pickup_field_one'); //создание поля

function custom_store_pickup_field_one( $fields ) {
  $fields['shipping']['side_1'] = $_POST['sides_1'];
  $fields['shipping']['side_2'] = $_POST['sides_2'];
 return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' ); //обновление чекаута
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['sides_1'])) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'side_1',  $_POST['sides_1']  );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'side_2',  $_POST['sides_2']  );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 ); // Вывод в админке
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p style="color:red"><strong>'.__('Слой 1: ').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'side_1', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p style="color:red"><strong>'.__('Слой 2: ').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'side_2', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Аттрибут он на то и аттрибут, чтобы однозначно идентифицировать определённое свойство товара. Если это цвет, то он один, или их несколько, но это остаётся один аттрибут - разноцветно).
Каждый аттрибут имеет уникальный ИД, который повсеместно используется системой. Вся система настроена на простую логику - один ИД = один аттрибут.

Два путя предвижу я:

Раз: кастомизация атрибутов. Добавляете аттрибут, который будет собирать значения других аттрибутов в себя. Тогда в базе под уникальным ИД будет храниться, например, строка с перечисленными аттрибутами одной группы, или с с теми же айдишниками.

Два: ищите плагин, который сделает это за вас. Вот, [например](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/)